# Get the last occurrence of counter

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

consider my xml file:

```
<Record>
   <AA bac="1" kjd="Same"/>
   <BB dfd="02" dad="342"/>
   <CC pod="11-A" dsd="11-B"/>
   <CC pod="22-A" dsd="22-B"/>
   <CC pod="33-A" dsd="33-B"/>
   <CC pod="44-A" dsd="44-B"/>
   <CC pod="55-A" dsd="55-B"/>
   <CC pod="66-A" dsd="66-B"/>
   <CC pod="77-A" dsd="77-B"/>
</Record>
```

I need to add another attribute (cnt) under the element CC, which is the counter for every 3 occurrences of CC. If it reaches 4, i need to increment it. I already did that part, but I need to get the last value of @cnt in CC and place it in one new (@cnt_1) of the attribute in AA.

Here is my xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Record">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* except CC"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="CC" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 3">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                <xsl:with-param name="group-pos" select="position()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="CC">
    <xsl:param name="group-pos"/>
    <CC cnt="{$group-pos}" seq="{position()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    </CC>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="CC/@*[not(normalize-space())]"/>
<xsl:template match="BB/@*[not(normalize-space())]" />
<xsl:template match="AA/@*[not(normalize-space())]" />
```

expected output:

```
<Record>
   <AA cnt_1="3" bac="1" kjd="Same"/>
   <BB dfd="02" dad="342"/>
   <CC cnt="1" seq="1" pod="11-A" dsd="11-B"/>
   <CC cnt="1" seq="2" pod="22-A" dsd="22-B"/>
   <CC cnt="1" seq="3" pod="33-A" dsd="33-B"/>
   <CC cnt="2" seq="1" pod="44-A" dsd="44-B"/>
   <CC cnt="2" seq="2" pod="55-A" dsd="55-B"/>
   <CC cnt="2" seq="3" pod="66-A" dsd="66-B"/>
   <CC cnt="3" seq="1" pod="77-A" dsd="77-B"/>
</Record>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:template match="AA">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="cnt_1" select="ceiling(count(../CC ) div 3)"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```